# Escape all characters inside Oracle LIKE Operator

Tags: c#, oracle, escaping, sql-like

I would like to escape all characters inside a string that is used with the LIKE operator in Oracle? Is this possible? If not can it be done with C#?

So far I have the code:

```
questions.RowFilter = "question_text LIKE '" + _questionIdToTextMappings[id].ToString() + "'";
```

However it breaks when the array value has square brackets in it, is there a way to treat that value from the array purely as a string and ignore all special characters like square brackets, percentage sign, etc? Either with Oracle or C#?

Comment: why do you use `like` here?

Comment: @IlyaBursov I'ved used the = operator now, seems to be working fine. I may or may not have had a good reason to use the LIKE operator in the past ... I will stick with = for now, thanks :).

Comment: What type is `questions`? Is it a DataTable?

Comment: Never concatenate arguments into SQL. You're leaving yourself open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use parameterized queries instead, there is no reason not to.